# How to update time-to-live of an entry using Redisson client in Java?

Tags: java, redis, redisson

Let's say I'd like to store an object `A` in Redis using `RMapCacheReactive` and Redisson.
In the beginning, I put it into the map with 10 000 ms TTL by the key `B`. Right after that, I put the same object `A` by the same key `B` but with zero TTL.
According to the documentation, the put method "stores value mapped by the key with a specified time to live" so my expectation was that `A` would be stored in that map permanently.
However, it was actually removed after that 10 000 ms passed (it became impossible to get it using Redisson client).
Is there a thing that I got wrong?

I checked this behaviour on 3.13.4 and 3.12.5 versions of Redisson.

Comment: did you try setting TTL as -1?

Comment: RMapCacheReactive doesn't have such a method. And even if it has, shouldn't TTL be automatically changed after I put a new value by the same key with a new TTL?

Comment: That's what I'm saying using ttl=0 did not work likely since it didn't update the key ttl=0 means this key has no lifetime, -1 means infinite.

Comment: According to the documentation, 0 means infinity ("@param ttl - time to live for key\value entry. If 0 then stores infinitely."). If I try to use -1 instead of zero, I get an exception "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ttl can't be negative"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported this issue on GitHub https://github.com/redisson/redisson/issues/3078. Turned out that that was a bug that should be fixed in the next version (3.13.5).